# How To Animate Camera.lookAt using Three JS

Tags: three.js, webgl

I have a scene which renders a board with several objects. Clicking on one of the objects and by use of object picking I can get the object and animate the cameras position to sit in an 'overhead' view of the object. Then using the camera.lookAt method I can force the camera to look directly at the object.

I am noticing a quick jump at the start of my animation when calling camera.lookAt within the onUpdate method as it initially has a large distance to rotate to look at the object selected. Each subsequent call to camera.lookAt is tiny in comparison and is animated nicely.

```js
// Position the camera to fit
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(camera.position).to({
    x: selectedObject.position.x,
    y: selectedObject.position.y,
    z: 1
}).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut).onUpdate(function() {
    camera.lookAt(selectedObject.position);
}).onComplete(function() {
    camera.lookAt(selectedObject.position);
}).start();
```

Is there any way to animate the method or will I have to manually transform the matrix values of the camera to look at my selected object?

Here is a fiddle with an example. It uses WebGLRenderer so please use a suitable browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/fungus1487/SMLwa/

Thanks for any help.

Comment: as of today we now have 3 suitable browsers, what a difference 3 years makes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One thing you can do is tween both the camera position and the camera target (which you have to define).

```
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween( camera.position )
    .to( {
        x: selectedObject.position.x,
        y: selectedObject.position.y,
        z: 1
    } )
    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None ).onUpdate( function () {

        camera.lookAt( camera.target );

    } )
    .onComplete( function () {

        camera.lookAt( selectedObject.position );

    } )
    .start();

var tween = new TWEEN.Tween( camera.target )
    .to( {
        x: selectedObject.position.x,
        y: selectedObject.position.y,
        z: 0
    } )
    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None )
    .onUpdate( function () {

    } )
    .onComplete( function () {

        camera.lookAt( selectedObject.position );

    } )
    .start();
```

It's a little tricky, because the tween's need to run exactly concurrently, and they don't...
This is the reason for the camera.lookAt() call in the second tween.

Comment: How do you define camera.target, please? It's not defined in THREE.js.

Comment: @pkout As stated in the first line of the answer, it is something you have to define. It does not have to be a property of `camera`, however.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I don't know how I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

WestLangley's answer works but seems oddly lengthy. I used the following with a pre-defined position(xyz) and target(xyz). Using perspective camera and trackball controls.

```
new TWEEN.Tween( camera.position ).to( {
    x: position.x,
    y: position.y,
    z: position.z}, 600 )
  .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.EaseInOut).start();
new TWEEN.Tween( controls.target ).to( {
    x: target.x,
    y: target.y,
    z: target.z}, 600 )
  .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.EaseInOut).start();
```