# How to animate the camera in three.js to look at an object?

Tags: rotation, three.js, quaternions

In Three.js, I would like to have the camera looking at an object in the scene, and when I click on another object, to have the camera rotate smoothly to look at the new object. (i.e animate the rotation of the camera).

I´ve checked in SO and this is the most similar question :

[Three.js How to use quaternion to rotate camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665562/three-js-how-to-use-quaternion-to-rotate-camera)

I've also tried modifying the code in this [website](http://graphic-sim.com/12_look_towards.php) and I manage to get something like this http://jsfiddle.net/F7Bh3/

```
 var quat0 = mesh2.quaternion;
 var eye = mesh2.position;
 var center = mesh.position;
 var mat = new THREE.Matrix4();
 mat.lookAt(center, eye, new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0));
 var quat1 = new THREE.Quaternion();
 quat1.setFromRotationMatrix( mat );

 var qm = new THREE.Quaternion();

 deltaTheta = angleBetweenQuats(quat0,quat1);
 var frac =  0.2/deltaTheta;
 if (frac>1)  frac=1;

 mesh2.quaternion.slerp(quat1,frac);
 mesh2.quaternion.normalize();
```

But when I try to rotate the camera instead of the object all I get is: http://jsfiddle.net/5Peq9/1/

What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: For a more detailed answer to the same question, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567712/how-to-animate-camera-lookat-using-three-js

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to animate a camera smoothly in three.js using quaternions. It took me a while to figure it out, but once it is done it is beautiful to watch how nicely quaternions work.

The method is:

- store the initial quaternion
- define a target quaternion
- tween something from 0 to 1
- interpolate quaternions on every frame during the tween
- apply interpolated quaternion back to camera on every frame

And a quick example with the key parts of the code:

```
var camera       // camera
var cameraPos0   // initial camera position
var cameraUp0    // initial camera up
var cameraZoom   // camera zoom
var iniQ         // initial quaternion
var endQ         // target quaternion
var curQ         // temp quaternion during slerp
var vec3         // generic vector object
var tweenValue   // tweenable value 

// init camera
function setup()
{
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000)
    camera.position = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 80)
    cameraPos0 = camera.position.clone()
    cameraUp0 = camera.up.clone()
    cameraZoom = camera.position.z
}

// set a new target for the camera
function moveCamera(euler, zoom)
{
    // reset everything
    endQ = new THREE.Quaternion()
    iniQ = new THREE.Quaternion().copy(camera.quaternion)
    curQ = new THREE.Quaternion()
    vec3 = new THREE.Vector3()
    tweenValue = 0

    endQ.setFromEuler(euler)
    TweenLite.to(this, 5, { tweenValue:1, cameraZoom:zoom, onUpdate:onSlerpUpdate })
}

// on every update of the tween
function onSlerpUpdate()
{
    // interpolate quaternions with the current tween value
    THREE.Quaternion.slerp(iniQ, endQ, curQ, tweenObj.value)

    // apply new quaternion to camera position
    vec3.x = cameraPos0.x
    vec3.y = cameraPos0.y
    vec3.z = cameraZoom
    vec3.applyQuaternion(curQ)
    camera.position.copy(vec3)

    // apply new quaternion to camera up
    vec3 = cameraUp0.clone()
    vec3.applyQuaternion(curQ)
    camera.up.copy(vec3)
}
```

The last step is to find the target Euler rotation to pass to `moveCamera`. In my case I was using TrackballControls to find some interesting camera positions/rotations, then retrieving them with `euler = camera.rotation.clone()` and passing that as a target. For example:

```
 moveCamera(new THREE.Euler(2.20, -0.15, 0.55), 120)
```

An application of this method can be seen here: http://brunoimbrizi.com/experiments/#/08

Answer (score 4):

For those using the Tween.js library: I adapted imbrizi's example to rotate a group of objects. The same could be applied to the camera as well.

```
function tweenRotation(targetQuaternion, duration){
    //tweens between zero and 1 values along Quaternion's SLERP method (http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Quaternion)

    qm = new THREE.Quaternion(); //initiate an empty Qt to be filled by the .slerp function
    curQuaternion = group.quaternion; //the starting point of your rotation

    var tween = new TWEEN.Tween({t:0}).to({t:1}, duration)
        .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut )
        .onUpdate(function(){
            THREE.Quaternion.slerp(curQuaternion, targetQuaternion, qm, this.t);
            qm.normalize();
            group.rotation.setFromQuaternion(qm);
    });

   tween.start();
}
```

I had originally used Tween.js to tween between an original and a target vector, and used the group.lookat(vector) function to point the object at the tweened vector at each step. But I found it to give jerky, inconsistent results, especially when the original and target vectors were close to antiparallel. This method, using spherical linear interpolation (slerp) gave me much smoother results.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the previous answers and the docs I worked out this solution, which seems a bit cleaner.

```
const targetOrientation = new THREE.Quaternion().set(0, 0, 0, 1).normalize();
gsap.to({}, {
    duration: 2,
    onUpdate: function() {
        camera.quaternion.slerp(targetOrientation, this.progress());
    }
});
```

[slerp documenation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion.slerp)

Answer (score 1):

The camera has its own LookAt method. I suspect this is because the lookAt logic for a camera is slightly different than that of two 3d objects, because a camera's motion inversely affects the render view (move the camera right, and the scene appears to move left), so it requires inverse thinking or a specific method to hide that inverse logic.

I suggest you try the camera's lookAt.

Comment: Well, I tried the camera's lookAt method before asking this question. The problem for me with lookAt is that the camera changes its rotation immediately, and what I want is to animate the rotation of the camera from one object to another.  Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: How's about this:
1) make a copy of the camera matrix
2) use the camera lookAt to generate the destination matrix
3) use the decompose matrix routine in Three to break down both matrices into their translation, quat, and scale components.
4) use tween.js to interpolate between the values of the two decomposed matrices. 
done.

Answer (score 1):

## from 2021

The very simple answer I found to animate the camera:

If you use Orbit Controler is better if you animate the vector3's `controler.target`

```js
// Controls
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas)
controls.enableDamping = true;
....
// later in this code
gsap.to(controls.target, {...someObject3d.postion, duration: 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer seems correct, however, it allows you to look at a specific rotation, not to look at a target, so how are you suppose to get the specific rotation ?

This is how I've done it :

1. Get the current quaternion of your camera (initialQuaternion)
2. Create a clone of your camera
3. Make the clone look at the target using the lookAt method
4. The thing is, the lookAt method of the camera will actually make it look AWAY from the target, so you have two options :

- Either use the lookAt method directly, then invert the rotation
- Or compute the position the target should have so that when looking away from it, you actually look in the correct direction

6. Get the new quaternion of the clone (targetQuaternion)
7. By using an animation loop, do a slerp between the initialQuaternion and the targetQuaternion