# ThreeJS - stop slerp camera rotation from drifting around

Tags: three.js, rotation, quaternions

I'm currently working on a scene, with an object at the centre (0,0,0) and 6 other object orbiting it. I have a camera set up behind and slightly above an outer object, looking back to centre (camera.lookAt(0,0,0) etc).

I want to click an object and just for the camera to arc towards and face the clicked object. I'm using Quaternion.slerp to achieve this, and it sort of works, yet while the camera's moving, it sort of drifts about lazily then slowly focuses just off centre of the object.

So if I click an object to the left of the camera's FOV, it sort of drifts right a little before swinging left, and vice versa.

I found some help regarding movement with slerp, I was hoping to simply adapt it:

[How to animate the camera in three.js to look at an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401213/how-to-animate-the-camera-in-three-js-to-look-at-an-object)

**Setup**

```
    this._endQ = new Quaternion();
    this._iniQ = new Quaternion().copy(this._camera.quaternion);
    this._curQ = new Quaternion();

    this._vec3 = new Vector3();

    const euler = new Euler(this._cameraLookAtDestination.x, this._cameraLookAtDestination.y, this._cameraLookAtDestination.z);

    this._endQ.setFromEuler(euler);
```

**In renderloop**

```
    Quaternion.slerp(this._iniQ, this._endQ, this._curQ, pointInTime);

    this._vec3.x = this._cameraLookAtDestination.x;
    this._vec3.y = this._cameraLookAtDestination.y;
    this._vec3.z = this._cameraLookAtDestination.z;
    this._vec3.applyQuaternion(this._curQ);

    this._camera.lookAt(this._vec3);
```

Is this normal slerp behaviour, or is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT:**

I also noticed that each time I click an object to look at, the camera seems to reset its orientation, then rotates

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe the code provided doesn't include enough context for anybody to be able to help. As a stab in the dark - you seem to be initialising Euler class with a 3D vector (unless I misunderstood completely). However, Euler constructor [expects 3 angles in radians](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Euler). Could that be a problem?

Comment: Sorry @martin_pr it turned out to be a problem with my use of slerp. For one, I was passing the wrong parameters to slerp (always good), and two (this may sound totally wrong) the slerp function, being 'spherical interpolation', was creating a circular path, which when viewed from the singular point it's drawn around makes sense, but, as my parameters were wrong, I was tracking this circular path out a bit in front of the camera, so it appeared to be drifting around. When my parameters were resolved I actually just passed the `this._curQ` to my camera and it worked fine, sorry for hassle man