# three js geometries' position doesn't change

Tags: arrays, three.js, data-visualization

I placed several spheres on my canvas using Three.js.
To show the multiple spheres at different location, 
I went with the code as below.
However, I only see one sphere and to check the location of the spheres I did 
console.log( xxx.clone());

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 )
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
// end template here


var coord =[{"x":10,"y":0,"z":10},{"x":20,"y":0,"z":30},{"x":30,"y":0,"z":50},
            {"x":40,"y":0,"z":70},{"x":50,"y":0,"z":90},
            {"x":60,"y":0,"z":110},{"x":70,"y":0,"z":90},
            {"x":80,"y":0,"z":70},{"x":90,"y":0,"z":50},
            {"x":100,"y":0,"z":30},{"x":110,"y":0,"z":10}]
var sphr =[];

function drawsphre(){
    for (let i =0; i<coord.length; i++){

        var geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 100, 50, 50);
        var a = new THREE.Vector3(coord[i].x*100, coord[i].y, coord[i].z*10)
        geom.center(a)
        var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "yellow"});
        sphr[i] = new THREE.Mesh( geom, mat);
        sphr[i] = new THREE.Mesh(geom,mat);
        scene.add(sphr[i]);
        console.log(sphr[i].clone())

    }
}
drawsphre();

camera.position.x = 400;
camera.position.y = 300;
camera.position.z = 1000;

var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ); // soft white light
scene.add( light );

// White directional light at 70% intensity shining from the top.
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.7 );
scene.add( directionalLight );

// movement


renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

However,
The console log says all the spheres' position is default which is (0,0,0).
and on canvas I could only see one sphere.

According to three.js document, I need to go with vector3 to specify the position, but it doesn't seem like it's working.

Can any help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A geometry doesn't have position in the scene — it's just a bunch of triangles. Calling [`geometry.center()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.center) doesn't take an argument, and just shifts all the vertices in the geometry so they're centered around `0,0,0`.

If you want different meshes with the same shape (geometry) at different locations, reposition each *mesh* in the scene, rather than modifying the *geometry*.

```js
var geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 100, 50, 50);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "yellow"});

for ( var v of coords ) {
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  mesh.position.set( v.x, v.y, v.z );
  scene.add( mesh );
}
```

A couple other notes:

- It's most efficient to reuse geometry and materials when you can.
- It's most efficient to use `*BufferGeometry` classes instead of `*Geometry`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! especially the additional notes are really helpful!!
Can I ask you one mored if you don't mind? what would be the good solution if I want to move the spheres from one point to the other points one by one as animation? not just bouncing here and there, once they move, I don't want to move them anymore.

Comment: tweenjs would be one way to do this: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14568734/1314762 and http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/. If those aren't what you're looking for I'd suggest opening a new question. :)

Comment: Hi, I tried to use TimeLineMax. but it doesn't work maybe I should post another question thanks!